# Does WordPress drop down menu always default to not hidden?

Tags: wordpress, css, drop-down-menu

I created a menu and sub menus on my WordPress site. The theme was made by me from scratch. However, the submenus are always on display (instead of hidden when not active or hovered).

How do I make the submenus display only on hover? Does this kind of feature not exist in WordPress by default and need more code tweaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That is the expected behaviour. WordPress functions just output the code needed for the menu. We'll have to style the menu ourselves. Particularly, when the theme is coded from scratch. You could use the following CSS:

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

li:hover > .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```